# Core Plot: Additional axis not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have added an additional x axis to my plot space in order to show zero values:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *boldLineStyle = [xAxis.axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
boldLineStyle.lineWidth = 1;
boldLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
boldLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;

CPTXYAxis *xZeroAxis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
xZeroAxis.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
xZeroAxis.plotSpace = plotSpace;
xZeroAxis.axisLineStyle = boldLineStyle;
```

Interestingly, the labels on this axis are shown, but not the axis itself:

```
xZeroAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:naLabels];
xZeroAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
xyAxisSet.axes = @[xAxis, xLabelAxis, yAxis, xZeroAxis];
```

How would I need to change my code to show the x axis?

Thank you!

[image]

`x.axisLineStyle` is set as follows:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
axisLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
```

Comment: What is `xAxis.axisLineStyle`? If it is `nil`, the `boldLineStyle` will be, too.

Comment: @Eric, I have added my code for `x.axisLineStyle`. It seems that my chart is not showing any axes (x, xZeroAxis, y). Could you look at it again, please? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code posted in the question.

Comment: @Eric, is it possible that my issue has to do with the latest Core Plot updates? I pulled the last Core Plot release about a week ago and have this issue since then. I am using Core Plot for three different charts in my app and each one of them has now missing axes since the update. I didn't change my code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current Core Plot release. The issue has been reported here: [Core Plot Issue 514](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=514&sort=-id)